# flask-wtf field rendered examples

Tags: python, html, wtforms

I'm comparing wtforms fields (http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/fields.html) to `<input>` tags (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp). for some fields in wtforms, the `<input type>` equivalents are easily guessed. but for others, I really don't know how they could be implemented.

Is there any example web pages where I can try rendered wtform fields? or is there some collection of templates for wtforms so I can try them myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily find out by just looking at the source:

```
# ... snip ...
class SearchField(core.StringField):
    """
    Represents an ``<input type="search">``.
    """
    widget = widgets.SearchInput()


class TelField(core.StringField):
    """
    Represents an ``<input type="tel">``.
    """
    widget = widgets.TelInput()


class URLField(core.StringField):
    """
    Represents an ``<input type="url">``.
    """
    widget = widgets.URLInput()
# ... snip ...
```

- [html5.py](https://bitbucket.org/simplecodes/wtforms/src/c4f179614c36/wtforms/fields/html5.py?at=default) (You probably want this one)
- [simple.py](https://bitbucket.org/simplecodes/wtforms/src/c4f179614c36/wtforms/fields/simple.py?at=default) (Or this)
- [core.py](https://bitbucket.org/simplecodes/wtforms/src/c4f179614c36/wtforms/fields/core.py?at=default)